# Woocommerce DISABLE autocomplete € 0 orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I wish i could just use Uncle Google but he serve me only what i DON'T want :D

I have a free Product on my website. But I want to check every order manualy, because it's only for company accounts and not for "customers".
But every order will set the Status to approved - or what ever in english language- and the order is complete.
The user has automaticaly acces to "restricted area" and that's what I don't want. I want to check every order manualy and pick every spam account.
I can imagine, this is going to work with only one simple function but I can't get it. It's only one free Product, other  Products are for moneeeeey.

It would be great if somebody has the same issue and can help me :)

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following function in your active theme functions.php. Check all default statuses here and change on-hold to what you want - https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_order_statuses/

```
function change_free_order_status( $order_id ) {  
    if ( ! $order_id ) {return;}            
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if($order->get_total() <= 0):
        $order->update_status( 'on-hold' ); // Change to what you need 
    endif;
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou','change_free_order_status');
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's not working... or do I have to change something? on-hold would be great

Comment: Its tested. Can you explain what exacatly its not working ? Can you debug ?